# Batch file Registry Query

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file that queries a registry entry to find the DisplayName.  If it finds the DisplayName matches a certain version number, it adds a key to another registry hive. If it does not match a certain version number, it does nothing and exists...

The problem I'm having is this logic works as long as the registry key exists I'm checking exists.  If it doesn't exist, it adds the key to the registry anyway.

Is there a good way to say up front that if the registry key doesn't exist at all to just exit? I would have thought in checking the display version that the key not existing would constitute the display name not matching and thus the code exiting but apparently not.

```
@echo off
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B8B03F49-B83A-4DD4-8925-10440664515E} /v DisplayVersion

for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B8B03F49-B83A-4DD4-8925-10440664515E} /v DisplayVersion') do (
if %%i EQU 3.5.0.88 goto exist
if %%i NEQ 3.5.0.88 goto not_exist
)

:exist
reg add HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Temp\{B8B03F49-B83A-4DD4-8925-10440664515E} /v DisplayVersion /t REG_SZ /d 3.5.0.88

:not_exist
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key does not exist you are falling though the FOR LOOP and executing the reg add. You need to add an EXIT statement on the line after the closing paren for the FOR LOOP.